# (active directory)How to authorize an user to use a permission required software/application?

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to  authorize a user to use a permission required software/application.

I've tried two ways:

**1.** I built up a OU under current OU and add the user into it.

Then, set up a GPO : Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Windows settings-> Software Restriction Policies -> Others

Right click-> New Path Policy

Paste the path of the application and set the security level to "unrestricted"

**2** https://thesysadminchannel.com/add-local-administrators-via-gpo-group-policy/

Neither worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should use AppLocker, "Software Restriction Policies" are [deprecated](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-10-deprecated-features) since Windows Vista and you should not use that anymore.

The documentation about AppLocker is available here, including the design guide and deployment guide :

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/applocker-overview

Comment: I would note for the OP that the feature is available only on Windows 10 Enterprise, Educational's version.